# How do I download the HTML code of the url with the images NOT being hidden

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I am trying to do some webscraping but when I download the html of the url the images are hidden but in my browser they are not "user-ad-row__image image image--is-hidden" instead of "user-ad-row__image image image--is-visible". Was seeing if webclient changed anything. Using the HtmlAgilityPack.

```
var url = "https://www.gumtree.com.au/s-motorcycles-scooters/wa/drz+400/k0c18322l3008845";
                var httpClient = new HttpClient();
                var html = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
                var htmlDocument = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

                WebClient client = new WebClient();

                htmlDocument.LoadHtml(client.DownloadString(url));
```

````
    <div class="user-ad-row__main-image-wrapper user-ad-row__main-image-wrapper--has-image"><img class="user-ad-row__image image image--is-hidden" src="" alt="Suzuki Drz-400E"></div>
</div>
<div class="user-ad-row__details">
    <div class="user-ad-row__info">
        <p class="user-ad-row__title">Suzuki Drz-400E</p>
        <div class="user-ad-price user-ad-price--row"><span class="user-ad-price__price">$4,250</span>
            <!-- -->
            <!-- --><span class="user-ad-price__price-negotiable user-ad-price__price-negotiable--with-price">Negotiable</span>
            <!-- -->
            <!-- -->
            <!-- -->
        </div>
        <ul class="user-ad-attributes">
            <li class="user-ad-attributes__attribute">Learner Approved</li>
            <li class="user-ad-attributes__attribute">6000 km</li>
        </ul>
        <p id="user-ad-desc-MAIN-1228533281" class="user-ad-row__description user-ad-row__description--regular">For sale 2008 Drz-400E excellent condition, well looked after starts first time evertime serviced about a month ago. Just paid 3 months rego. Call or text </p>
    </div>
    <div class="user-ad-row__extra-info">
        <div class="user-ad-row__location"><span class="user-ad-row__location-area">Perth City Area</span>Perth<span class="user-ad-row__distance"> </span></div>
        <p class="user-ad-row__age">15/09/2019</p>
    </div>
</div>
<button id="" type="button" class="user-ad-row__watchlist-heart-wrapper watchlist-heart Button__buttonBase--3YR6h Button__button--2NsdC Button__buttonBasic--3CSBx" role=""><span class="" aria-hidden="true"><span class="icon-heart heart"></span></span>
</button>```
````

Comment: What User Agent value are you using in your web client calls? The site will serve the page based on how it sees your web client calls.

Answer (score 1):

The website that you provided loads images using Javascript and according to an internet search it appears that HtmlAgilityPack only renders the HTML but is unable to run Javascript.

Some solutions would be:

#### [WebBrowser Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8)

It's kind of tricky if you want to mix it with the HtmlAgilityPack but provides decent performance.

#### [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org)

You can use Selenium+a webdriver for your prefered browser (Chrome, Firefox, PhantomJS). It is somewhat slow but is very flexible.

#### [Javascript.Net](https://github.com/JavascriptNet/Javascript.Net)

It allows you to run scripts using Chrome's V8 JavaScript engine. Near the bottom of the page there will be something like `<script src="/latest/resources/react/app.full.something.js"></script>`

If you are able to figure out how that loads then you should be able to get all of the images.